# Can "crouch" be used to indicate motion?

Tags: word-usage

Can "crouch" be used to indicate motion?

Example:

> I crouched to the edge of the cliff and stayed there, still.

(So in this example I'm using crouched as a synonym for *walking "crouchley"*

Is this a common usage? If not, what's a better alternative?

Comment: I suggest "**I crouched my way** to the edge of the cliff".

Comment: "Can 'crouch' be used to indicate motion?" No, but there's nothing preventing it being used as in the example -- one can crouch **while** moving or move while in the process of crouching down.

Comment: However, it'd seem a better way to say would be "I crouched, **towards** (suggests movement) the edge of the cliff and stayed there, still."

Comment: Here you can find a few examples of 'crouch towards' suggesting movement!! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2Ccrouched+towards&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrouched%20towards%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yes, *crouch* can signify movement: namely, the movement you make to change from a standing to a crouching position. It's not a movement that will get you from point A to point B. I would interpret your example as a non-native speaker's attempt to say "I crouched down at the edge of the cliff...".

Comment: The only satisfactory way of saying this which I can think of is *He moved forward in crouched position to the edge of the cliff*. One cannot use the verb 'crouch' to mean walk, because it means 'crouch'.

Comment: Normally (in the US) "crouch" does not imply motion (other than the motion required to achieve the crouched position).  I would have said "crept to the edge..." or "crept to the edge in a crouch..." or some such.  But most people would properly understand "crouched to the edge..." from the context.  The sentence is not necessary poor writing, though, since in a story it is often helpful to trim down the verbiage a bit to keep the pace up, and slightly obscure usages ofter help to keep the reader alert and interested.

Comment: I want to second Hot Licks. Not standard but conveys the meaning intended. I say use it. Crouch English forward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: yes, but that said, crouch is usually *not* used in combination with forward or backward motion, i.e., one doesn't usually walk in a crouch or with a crouching posture.

**crouch** (*krouch*) *verb*. *crouched*, *crouch*·*ing*, *crouch*·*es*, *intransitive verb.*

> 1. a.  To stoop, especially with the knees bent: ***crouched over the grate, searching for his keys***. b.  To press the entire body close to the ground with the limbs bent: a cat crouching near its prey.
> 2. To bend servilely or timidly; cringe. v.tr.
>    To bend (the head or knee, for example) low, as in fear or humility.

[Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crouch)

> *noun* The act or posture of bending low or crouching.

Answer (score 2):

It's not common... a better way to impart your image would be to say:

"I crawled/climbed/made my way to the edge of the cliff and crouched there, still."

Answer (score 1):

There are several examples of **crouch[ed] along** if you google it.

For example, from [*Hatari*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6PI1fd3d0vkC&pg=PA273&lpg=PA273&dq=crouched%20along&source=bl&ots=FOR_fUupYC&sig=bhsu_dI71ZeA5Cgu1p63PVw_HJ0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sey8VK-GL4P6UI24hJgD&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=crouched%20along&f=false) by Ernie Palamarek:

> Throwing myself over, I joined Lauren on the deck. We crouched along
>   the bulwarks as we made our way forward in the darkness.

[Revenge of the Golden Dragon](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3T-juQCAos8C&pg=PT28&lpg=PT28&dq=%22crouched%20along%22&source=bl&ots=osv-UZ_dVT&sig=QikcnjTOrAi3Xnl-EE4DEcjvzZk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8-68VKLPG47-aOLLgMgF&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22crouched%20along%22&f=false) by GoodLoe:

> Two imposing large dark figures emerged over the wall from the fire
>   escape and dropped quietly onto the patio. They crouched along the
>   opposite wall from where I hid...

Comment: In both those examples, "along" seems to mean alongside - I don't think continuous movement is implied during the crouching.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be a problem as I'm having no luck finding a synonym. Duck-walk is now out of use. I've come up with "moved forward still crouched," "remained crouched as he moved forward," "forward in a crouched position," etc. Hope that helps others looking for a solution.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but a confession of not being able to find an answer. As a new user of SE EL&U you will get more out of the site (and not have your posts mysteriously deleted) if you take the [Introductory Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [how to answer questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please.